Can monaco editor keep default suggestions even after providing a custom suggestion
Does monaco editor supports to keep its default suggestions of any text entered within the editor even when there are custom suggestions overridden using registerCompletionItemProvider?
What am trying to find is whether it has a support on any of its version?
Tried following this approach but nothing is satisfying or simple enough https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/discussions/3824
